# scjp question regarding design

Tags: java, scjp, oop

A team of programmers is reviewing a proposed API for a new utility class. After some
discussion, they realize that they can reduce the number of methods in the API without
losing any functionality. If they implement the new design, which two OO principles will
they be promoting?

> ```
> A. Looser coupling
> B. Tighter coupling
> C. Lower cohesion
> D. Higher cohesion
> E. Weaker encapsulation
> F. Stronger encapsulation
> ```

Can somebody tell me what is the answer?

Comment: @Suresh I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Is this homework? Exam sample question?

Comment: Math class in java is an utility API. Look at their methods.

Comment: @G_H SCJP stands for Sun Certified Java Programmer (I've passed the exam for it). So it must be an exam sample question.

Comment: @Suresh Did you read the whole question? I don't see how the Math class is relevant.

Comment: @Robin Green Of course... should've noticed that. I thought SCJP sounded familiar. But I was thinking of JSPC, the JSP precompiler for Maven :D  By the time I read the question it had already vanished from my ridiculously short attention span.

Comment: My answer is the correct one, not GuruKulki's! I have passed the SCJP exam!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer will be

**Looser coupling** and 
**Higher cohesion**

If the next question is why? then I would suggest you to go through this article :

http://blog.sanaulla.info/2008/06/26/cohesion-and-coupling-two-oo-design-principles/

Comment: I don't think it's cohesion because the methods could be removed without losing any functionality. This indicates the overall functionality of the class has not changed.

Comment: @Robin Green, If the same method is used for more than one purposes, then it will be hard to remove that without affecting the functionality. you can check in the link given for details on cohesion.

Comment: I agree with your comment, but it is irrelevant to the question! You are first making a dubious assumption about the *previous* design (that it is cohesive), but this doesn't matter anyway because the question does not ask about the *previous* design, it asks about the *new* design!

Answer (score 1):

I would say, firstly, stronger encapsulation. Suppose one of the methods that is no longer in the API (i.e. it's been made private, or deleted) provides more "low-level" functionality that can still be accessed via the remaining "higher-level" methods. I think that's what you're supposed to assume. In that case, you have improved encapsulation because you can freely change the number and type of arguments to the method, the name of the method, and its return type, or even delete the method entirely and fold its functionality into its caller(s), without affecting clients of the API.

Oh sorry, which **two**? OK, it will also promote looser coupling, because there are fewer points of coupling between the class and its clients, and thus fewer opportunities to break things in different ways.